# How to load machine learning model in python 3.6 that is trained on python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have trained a machine learning model on Python `3.5`, and now I switched to Google Colab, which uses Python `3.6`, and when I try to load the model that I have trained on Python `3.5`, it gives this error:

```
SystemError: unknown opcode.
```

After googling, I found that this error occurs because of the environment change, then I cross-checked my python version, and both Python version were different. How can I load my model on Python `3.6`?

Comment: You can try loading up your model into memory using python 3.5 then saving your model using python 3.6 as the interpreter.

Comment: How exactly are you saving and loading the model? Please add code if possible.

Comment: One way to get python 3.5 version is to connect to a [local runtime](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't.

Even if you get it to run without errors / warnings, there might be slight changes under the hood that change the behavior / performance of the model.

You should either retrain the model on Python 3.6 or create a virtual environment that runs Python 3.5 for your model to ensure it performs as expected. Also always ensure that the actual libraries (e.g. keras...) have the same version.

Comment: When you say performance, do you mean speed of execution, or metrics performance? Also, if you have no choice to retrain, is it ok to just load_weights(...)?

Comment: Both. Not sure about load_weights, since I don't know which algorithm you are using. You can try it and hope for the best, as long as all the library versions are the same you _might_ be good.

Comment: Also, maybe make sure that the change from 3.5 to 3.6 is actually the problem and not something else, e.g. a different implementation of Python with a more limited set of commands.

Comment: I have read that loading weights maybe a safer and better "practice" than loading the whole serialized model from a saved .h5, esp. if you have control over each phase of the ML dev. If i remember correct, this is the only way for pytorch (used this almost a yr ago).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem as you did. I trained my model on a GCP on python 3.5 and move it to colab to continue with evaluation which is python 3.6.

What I did is to reinstantiate the exact model from code, and then call load_weights:

```
model = create_my_model()

model.load_weights('my_model_trained_with_py_35.h5')

model.save('my_model_py36.h5')
```

For my case, I don't have lot of custom code other than a Lambda with:

```
def abs_diff(x):
  return tf.abs(x[0] - x[1])
```

Since your model could be arbitrarily more complex, this may or may not work, but it is worth a try esp. if re-training is too expensive. As usual, evaluate the model with the same data and ensure nothing is strange.